# How to test a Greasemonkey script, especially on a local copy of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, greasemonkey

I have my own javascript that I need to test with Greasemonkey. I've never worked with Greasemonkey before; How do I test the script?

I am not testing it on the World Wide Web, I have saved the target page (**Firefox > Save page as > Web page, complete**), so I am testing it locally.

What is the process? How do I test the script?

Comment: This is a rather broad question for SO. Perhaps you're better off going through the Greasemonkey documentation and tutorials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some guidelines for troubleshooting Greasemonkey scripts, both in general, and on local copies of webpages.

1. For testing on local pages (without a local web-server), you must change a setting of Greasemonkey.
   Open [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) and set `greasemonkey.fileIsGreaseable` to `true`
2. Make sure the local copy of the webpage is not in the system's `/tmp` or `/temp` folder(s).  The script will not work reliably, if it is.
3. Make sure the script source is not in the system's `/tmp` or `/temp` folder(s).  [The script will not install if it is](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Troubleshooting_%28Script_Authors%29#Installing_from_.2Ftmp).
4. For a script to work on local files, be sure you have an appropriate [`@include` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40include) aimed at the local webpage copy.  For example:

   ```
   // @include file:///D:/web/local%20page%20copies/*
   ```
5. Familiarize yourself with Firefox's error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) and [how it can be used to determine the source of errors in Greasemonkey scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627507/331508).
6. Install [Firebug](https://www.getfirebug.com/) and get familiar with it.   [Firebug's excellent console functions](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) work great from within a GM script -- although you *might* have to preface them with `unsafeWindow.`.
7. Test as much of the javascript as you can, that doesn't use [GM_ functions](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Category:API_Reference), in Firebug's JavaScript console first.

**See also:**

- [Troubleshooting for Script Authors](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Troubleshooting_%28Script_Authors%29)
- [Avoid Common Pitfalls in Greasemonkey](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Avoid_Common_Pitfalls_in_Greasemonkey)