# Javascript Debugging Outside FireFox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, greasemonkey, javascript-debugger

I have a greasemonkey script running on Firefox and its in an infinite loop. I can't figure out where loop is at because I am unable to have a debug window that is not tied to FireFox.

How can I set-up firefox so I can monitor the console log even if firefox dies on me. Currently I am using firebug, it dies with FireFox instant.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried using Chrome console to debug the application?

Comment: Set a breakpoint instead of trying to log

Comment: Unfortunately, Greasemonkey does not play nice with Firebug.  You can, with some difficulty, set breakpoints and watch expressions.  However, it will only honor the first breakpoint and ignores everything as soon as you try to continue or step.  You still have to develop and debug [the old-fashioned way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839628/331508).

Comment: lol I didn't realise you can set breakpoints in GM scripts. Total Newbie here. XD Thanks that's the perfect pain in the arse solution. But it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using ConsoleExport Firebug extension can solve your problem. It has autoexport feature and maybe before crash it can dump console logs to a file. For more information:
http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/consoleexport/

Answer (score 0):

Answered above by bfavaretto and Brock Adams :)

It seems you can set breakpoints in GM scripts using Firebug. I didn't know this.